# Django E-Commerce: cart item Iterations not pushed to db

Tags: python, django, shopping-cart

I have the following model in my orders app:

```
class Order(models.Model):  
    # customer info
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

I have the following create_order view:

```
def create_order(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateNewOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()

            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product=item['product'], price=item['price'], quantity=item['quantity'])
                cart.clear()
     else:
         form = CreateNewOrderForm()
```

**PROBLEM**

On creating a new order, if my cart contained multiple products, I can only see 1 (the first) product in my OrderItem.

Any advice on how to rectify this?
or
on where to look?

Comment: Maybe this line here? `cart.clear()` - Probably want to move that out of the for loop I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the identation in the line , cart.clear() , it should be out of the "for" loop

try this,

```
for item in cart:
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product=item['product'], 
            price=item['price'], quantity=item['quantity'])
cart.clear()
```

Comment: Indeed. It seems I was clearing my cart after the 1st iteration. Thanks.